# Set custom "_id" to ElasticSearch using JSON file

Tags: json, elasticsearch

I am new to ElasticSearch and I need to know if it is possible to assign a custom id to my input. I am using the LinkSO dataset. The JSON file should look like this:

```
{"index": {"_id": "11"}}
{"title": "title1", "body": "body1", "answer": "answer1"}
{"index": {"_id": "22"}}
{"title": "title2", "body": "body2", "answer": "answer2"}
```

My PUT command is

```
PUT /test
{
  "settings": {
    "analysis": {
      "analyzer": {
        "my_analyzer": {
          "tokenizer": "whitespace",
          "filter": [
            "lowercase",
            "porter_stem"
          ]
        }
      }
    }
  },
  "mappings": {
    "properties": {
      "title": {
        "type": "text",
        "analyzer": "my_analyzer",
        "similarity": "BM25"
      },
      "body": {
        "type": "text",
        "analyzer": "my_analyzer",
        "similarity": "BM25"
      },
      "answer": {
        "type": "text",
        "analyzer": "my_analyzer",
        "similarity": "BM25"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

I am using this command on cmd

```
curl -s -H "Content-Type: application/json" -XPOST localhost:9200/test/_doc/_bulk --data-binary "@test.json"
```

When inserting only one json data like

```
{"title": "title1", "body": "body1", "answer": "answer1"}
```

It works fine. The data is inserted and I get the output. But whenever I try to add 2 data like

```
{"title": "title1", "body": "body1", "answer": "answer1"}
{"title": "title2", "body": "body2", "answer": "answer2"}
```

The json file shows end of file expected error. The same happens when I use add index on the json file.

Can someone guide me how to work it and how can I add the "_id" as well because ElasticSearch is giving id on its own as _bulk

Answer (score 0):

In your file you need to have the data as below. To set the id you need this line, {"index": {"_id": "11"}}, before each document. Another important point is to add a line break at the end of the file.

```
{"index": {"_id": "11"}}
{"title": "title1", "body": "body1", "answer": "answer1"}
{"index": {"_id": "22"}}
{"title": "title2", "body": "body2", "answer": "answer2"}
\n
```

Comment: Posts this error ```{"error":{"root_cause":[{"type":"mapper_parsing_exception","reason":"failed to parse"}],"type":"mapper_parsing_exception","reason":"failed to parse","caused_by":{"type":"illegal_argument_exception","reason":"Malformed content, found extra data after parsing: START_OBJECT"}},"status":400}```

Comment: show the content file.

Comment: what content file? I have to put the above json file in the PUT /test using Kibana

Comment: I understand that you are doing the ingestion via curl command. What I was referring to was the contents of the @test.json file that you are submitting.

Comment: When I am putting just `{"title": "title1", "body": "body1", "answer": "answer1"}` the curl ingestion is correct, I can see that the changes have been added. But when I am inputting more than that like `{"title": "title1", "body": "body1", "answer": "answer1"}
{"title": "title2", "body": "body2", "answer": "answer2"}` or even when adding index parameter as well, then I am getting error message in the json file as end of file expected. I am using VSCode. i want to bulk addition with the index code as well